# more than one odom->base_link transform

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, base-link, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using rtabmap rgbd_odometry node and data from IMU feeded to robot_pose_ekf node. This gives me stable odometry. This stable odometry data publishes a odom->base_link transform. Apart from this the rgbd_odometry node and robot_pose_ekf node also publishes the transform between odom and baselink. To avoid any conflict i remapped the frame id of rgbd_odometry and robot_pose_ekf as odom1 and odom_combined. But now when i run

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

The results are varying everytime i run the command. Sometimes it shows that odom-base_link transform is published by odom and at other point of time it shows that the same transform is published by rgbd_odometry. How can i select odom to be publishing this transform always ?

```
roswtf
```

gives me this.

```
ERROR TF re-parenting contention:
 * reparenting of [base_link] to [odom_combined] by [/robot_pose_ekf]
 * reparenting of [base_link] to [odom_useless] by [/rgbd_odometry]
 * reparenting of [base_link] to [odom] by [/odom]

ERROR TF multiple authority contention:
 * node [/robot_pose_ekf] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom_combined] already published by node [/odom]
 * node [/rgbd_odometry] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom_useless] already published by node [/robot_pose_ekf]
 * node [/odom] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom] already published by node [/rgbd_odometry]
 * node [/rgbd_odometry] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom_useless] already published by node [/odom]
 * node [/odom] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom] already published by node [/robot_pose_ekf]
 * node [/robot_pose_ekf] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom_combined] already published by node [/rgbd_odometry]
```

Please help me with this. I have been stuck at the same point since last 4 days.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198041/more-than-one-odom-%3Ebase_link-transform/) by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) represents coordinate frames and the transforms between them as a tree. This means each `frame_id` can only have one parent (but can have many children). You currently have three separate nodes publishing a transform from different frames into *base_link*: `robot_pose_ekf`, `rgbd_odometry`, and `odom`.

In other words, renaming only the *odom* frame coming from `robot_pose_ekf` isn't enough. If you had instead/also renamed the `child_frame_id` (*base_link*), it would have worked. Alternatively and preferably, the `rgbd_odometry` node may have a parameter that stops it from publishing its transform. Finally, you appear to have a third node publishing that transform (the `odom` node).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on 2014-11-23**:
Thank you Tom! I did the same with `robot_pose_ekf`. There was a parameter called publish_tf. I set it false, but somehow it was still publishing. I don't know if there is one for rgbd_odometry. It wasn't listed on their page. Is there a way that we can see all the parameters of the give node?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-23**:
Since `robot_pose_ekf` is going to have the best overall pose estimate in your system, you want it to publish that transform, and not the other nodes. Try `rosparam list` from a console to see what parameters are set. Other than the namespaces, I don't know if you can see who set what parameter.

**Comment by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on 2014-11-23**:
Thank you! But `rosparam list` only shows the parameters which i have already set in launch file.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-23**:
Perhaps you should post your launch file.